# Proper color names from colordialog

Tags: winforms, naming-conventions, colors

Whenever I run this, and open the color dialog, there are many colors that do not having a proper name, the listbox will show something like "ffff8000"(Orange-Yellow). Is there another way of pushing the proper name? Is there a proper Color Name library I can reference in code?

```
   colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
    cl.Add(colorDialog1.Color.Name);   
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(cl.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET framework defines the KnownColor enum, you could use it to convert a color value to a name.  It won't be a complete solution, it doesn't have "Orange Yellow".  But many of the common colors are present.  For example:

```
    public static Color LookupKnownColor(uint c) {
        int crgb = (int)(c & 0xffffff);
        foreach (KnownColor kc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))) {
            Color map = Color.FromKnownColor(kc);
            if (!map.IsSystemColor) {
                if ((map.ToArgb() & 0xffffff) == crgb)
                    return map;
            }
        }
        return Color.FromArgb(unchecked((int)(c | 0xff000000)));
    }
```

Usage:

```
 Color c = LookupKnownColor(0xffffff00);
 Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
```

Output: Yellow