# I created a color picker user control and when i drag and drop image then move the mouse over the colors i see r,g,b values and not names. why?

Tags: c#, winforms

when running the application first time the grid cells have all the same light green color.
and then when i put the mouse over one of the cells i see the label with the color name:

[image: showing the color name]

then i drag image into the control and get the colors but this time when i put the mouse over any of the cells i get the r,g,b values and not the name. is there a way to get the names or because there are so many possible colors the names are not built in the .net ?

now in this screenshot the mouse is over the black cell box or what i see as black:

[image: r,g,b values show instead names]

and what if i want to display in the grid for example only the colors that we can "see"  in our eyes of the image we drag into the control ?  and not getting all the 256 colors.

here is example of image that I dragged into the control. i can count in my eyes 16 colors and with the black 17 colors. but in the grid i will get 256 colors. i want to refactor the code and get only the colors we can "see".

[image: colors]

this is the method that should display the names:

```
private void CreateColorGrid()
{
    // Define the size of the grid and the color cells
    int gridSize = 20;
    int gridCols = 16;
    int gridRows = 16;

    // Initialize the grid with green transparent colors
    Color gridColor = Color.LightGreen; // Semi-transparent green

    for (int i = 0; i < gridCols * gridRows; i++)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label
        {
            AutoSize = false,
            Size = new Size(gridSize, gridSize),
            BackColor = gridColor,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
            Location = new Point(gridSize * (i % gridCols), gridSize * (i / gridCols)),
            Tag = i // Store the index or color information in the Tag property
        };

        // Set up the tooltip for each label
        lbl.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Label currentLabel = sender as Label;
            if (currentLabel != null)
            {
                // Get the name of the color if it is known, otherwise show the RGB value
                Color color = currentLabel.BackColor;
                string colorName = color.IsKnownColor ? color.Name : $"RGB: {color.R}, {color.G}, {color.B}";
                toolTip1.SetToolTip(currentLabel, colorName);
            }
        };

        lbl.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            Label currentLabel = s as Label;
            if (currentLabel != null)
            {
                SelectedColor = currentLabel.BackColor;
                // If you want to show a tooltip when a color is selected
                toolTip1.Show($"Selected: {SelectedColor.Name}", currentLabel, 1000); // Show for 1 second
            }
        };

        // Add the label to the UserControl's Controls collection
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
}
```

and the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ColorAnalyzer
{
    public partial class ImageColorPciker : UserControl
    {
        public Color SelectedColor { get; private set; }
        private ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

        public ImageColorPciker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.AllowDrop = true;
            this.DragEnter += ImageColorPciker_DragEnter;
            this.DragDrop += ImageColorPciker_DragDrop;

            // Create the color grid on initialization
            CreateColorGrid();
        }

        private void ImageColorPciker_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
        }

        private void ImageColorPciker_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                string filename = files[0];
                using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filename))
                {
                    ProcessImage((Bitmap)image);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ProcessImage(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            var colorCounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            try
            {
                int bytesPerPixel = 4;
                int byteCount = bmp.Width * bmp.Height * bytesPerPixel;
                byte[] pixels = new byte[byteCount];
                IntPtr ptrFirstPixel = data.Scan0;
                Marshal.Copy(ptrFirstPixel, pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
                int heightInPixels = data.Height;
                int widthInBytes = data.Width * bytesPerPixel;

                for (int y = 0; y < heightInPixels; y++)
                {
                    int currentLine = y * data.Stride;
                    for (int x = 0; x < widthInBytes; x = x + bytesPerPixel)
                    {
                        int argb = BitConverter.ToInt32(pixels, currentLine + x);
                        if (!colorCounts.ContainsKey(argb))
                            colorCounts[argb] = 1;
                        else
                            colorCounts[argb]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                bmp.UnlockBits(data);
            }

            var topColors = colorCounts.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).Take(256).Select(kvp => Color.FromArgb(kvp.Key)).ToArray();
            UpdateColorGrid(topColors);
        }

        private void UpdateColorGrid(Color[] colors)
        {
            // Assuming we have already created a grid of labels called 'colorCells'
            int index = 0;

            foreach (Label lbl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (index < colors.Length)
                {
                    lbl.BackColor = colors[index];
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl.BackColor = Color.LightGreen; // Default/fallback color
                }
                index++;
            }
        }

        private void CreateColorGrid()
        {
            // Define the size of the grid and the color cells
            int gridSize = 20;
            int gridCols = 16;
            int gridRows = 16;

            // Initialize the grid with green transparent colors
            Color gridColor = Color.LightGreen; // Semi-transparent green

            for (int i = 0; i < gridCols * gridRows; i++)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label
                {
                    AutoSize = false,
                    Size = new Size(gridSize, gridSize),
                    BackColor = gridColor,
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
                    Location = new Point(gridSize * (i % gridCols), gridSize * (i / gridCols)),
                    Tag = i // Store the index or color information in the Tag property
                };

                // Set up the tooltip for each label
                lbl.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Label currentLabel = sender as Label;
                    if (currentLabel != null)
                    {
                        // Get the name of the color if it is known, otherwise show the RGB value
                        Color color = currentLabel.BackColor;
                        string colorName = color.IsKnownColor ? color.Name : $"RGB: {color.R}, {color.G}, {color.B}";
                        toolTip1.SetToolTip(currentLabel, colorName);
                    }
                };

                lbl.Click += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Label currentLabel = s as Label;
                    if (currentLabel != null)
                    {
                        SelectedColor = currentLabel.BackColor;
                        // If you want to show a tooltip when a color is selected
                        toolTip1.Show($"Selected: {SelectedColor.Name}", currentLabel, 1000); // Show for 1 second
                    }
                };

                // Add the label to the UserControl's Controls collection
                this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            }
        }

        private void ImageColorPciker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The [known colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.knowncolor) are very few (175, including the System's defined ones), over 16.7 millions...

Comment: and what if i want to refactor my code and to get only the known colors i mean not to see the names still to see the r,g,b values but when dragging the image inside instead getting 256 colors to get only the colors we can "see"  in our eyes.  for example if i drag image that i painted in paint with two colors red and green and drawn 5 lines i want that it will show only the two colors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953528/17034

Comment: "for example if i drag image that i painted in paint with two colors red and green and drawn 5 lines i want that it will show only the two colors. " You would need a color quantization algorithm for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got it right – there [are only so many named colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colors?view=windowsdesktop-8.0):

[image]